# WPF VisualStateManager.GoToState

Tags: wpf, visualstatemanager

I try to change the state for all the buttons in my program

I got this style for button:

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="StateMouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation  Storyboard.TargetName="UpperBorder" Duration="00:00:0.5"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF5086C4"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="StatePressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation  Storyboard.TargetName="UpperBorder" Duration="00:00:0.05"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="#FF21214E"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="StateDisabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation  Storyboard.TargetName="UpperBorder" Duration="00:00:0.5"  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Lower" Cursor="Hand"   BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4" Background="Gray" ></Border>
                        <Border MouseEnter="UpperBorder_MouseEnter" x:Name="UpperBorder" Cursor="Hand"  CornerRadius="4"   Background="#FF0657E8">
                            <Border.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10"/>
                            </Border.Effect>
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter Cursor="Hand" Margin="8,8,8,8"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

in this event: `MouseEnter="UpperBorder_MouseEnter` I want the change will take effect on ***all the buttons*** in my program (but the function VisualStateManager.GoToState take as parameter only spesific button)
how can I do that?

Comment: Are you saying that if you have three buttons and the user mouses over one button you want all three button borders to change at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The [button](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.button.aspx) already have MouseOver state in CommonStates group. See [Button Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx). The state auto set in the Button class when mouse over.

Is that what you want ?